# Outward Flux through a partial cylinder Without using Divergence Theorm.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Hello I'm trying to calculate the following without using Divergence theorem.

Given the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(xy+2xz,x^2+y^2,xy-z)$ and the surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ bound by the planes $z=y-2$ and $z=0$ calculate the outward flux.

So I tried to set up the surface integral by parameterizing the surface into two pieces $f(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{4-y^2},y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)=(-\sqrt{4-y^2},y,z)$ and the bounds of integration y-2<z<0 and -2<y<2. I calculate the normal of the surface to be $(\pm 1, \frac{y}{\sqrt{4-y^2}},0)$ so then I calculate the unit normal to be $(\pm\frac{\sqrt{4-y^2}}{2},\frac{y}{2},0)$ and set up the integral and get $\int^2_{-2}\int^0_{y-2}4ydzdy$. But the correct answer is $-12\pi$. So my question is what should the correct integral be, and where am I going wrong?

Comment: The outward normal to the cylinder at a point $(x,y,z)$ is $(x,y,0)$. The unit normal will be $(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},0 )$.

Comment: @PierreCarre that makes sense, but I can't set up the surface integral by parametrizing in the xy-plane so I need to find the normal in terms of yz-plane or xz-plane.

Comment: Did you consider the flux through the $z=0$ and $z=y-2$ surfaces?

Comment: @andrei I did not. but I must, thank you!

Comment: It says surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 4$ so you should not include the planes. In any case, flux through both planes is zero. $z = 0$ is obvious but even the flux through the other one is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is always good practice to choose a parametrization that represents the whole surface.

Secondly, $-12 \pi$ is incorrect answer unless there are typo in the question.

Thirdly, there must be mistakes how you arrived at the final integral. It does not simplify to what you wrote. Also note that if you do the dot product with unit normal vector, you will have to use a factor to map surface area element to area of the projection in yz plane. Here is the correct integral using your approach,

The unit normal vector is $ \hat n =  \left(\cfrac{x}{2}, \cfrac{y}{2}, 0 \right)$

So, $\vec F \cdot \hat n = x^2 (y + z) + \cfrac{y^3}{2}$

Now using $x = \sqrt{4-y^2}$ and $ds = \sqrt{1 + (x')^2} \ dy \ dz$, the integral is,

$\displaystyle 2 \int_{-2}^2 \int_{y-2}^0 \left((4-y^2) (y + z) + \frac{y^3}{2} \right) \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-y^2}} \ dz \ dy$

$ = - 40 \pi$

In fact, you can confirm this result using divergence theorem.

Here is what would be a better parametrization given it is a cylinder,

$r(\theta, z) = (2\cos\theta, 2 \sin \theta, z), 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi, 2 \sin\theta - 2 \leq z \leq 0$

$r_{\theta} \times r_z = (2 \cos\theta, 2\sin\theta, 0)$

$ \vec F(x,y,z)=(xy+2xz,x^2+y^2,xy-z)$

So, $\vec F (r(\theta, z)) = (2 \sin2\theta + 4z \cos\theta, 4, 2 \sin2\theta - z)$

$\vec F \cdot (r_{\theta} \times r_z) = 4 \sin2\theta \cos\theta + 8 z \cos^2\theta + 8 \sin\theta$

So integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{2 \sin\theta - 2}^0 (4 \sin2\theta \cos\theta + 8 z \cos^2\theta + 8 \sin\theta) \ dz \ d\theta = - 40 \pi$

After you integrate wrt $z$ and while integrating wrt $\theta$, you can avoid integrating functions whose integral is zero over $(0, 2\pi)$. That should simplify working to some extent.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the answer and gained a lot from my mistakes and your answer. I have one concern about ds=sqrt(4-y^2)dzdy. I got ds=2/sqrt(4-y^2)dzdy; Interesting I evaluated the integral using both ds and got the same answer.

Comment: @Mars thanks. yes as we have two surfaces on positive x and negative x, I multiplied by $2$ which is outside the integral as you may notice. So what you did and what I did seems to be the same.

Comment: @Math_Lover I understand why you multiplied by 2, What I want to discuss is when I calculated the surface area element I get 2÷sqrt(4-y^2) whereas you get sqrt(4-y^2). To show my work I get the norm of the surface area element is sqrt(1^2+(y/sqrt(4-y^2)^2))= sqrt(1+y^2/(4-y^2))=sqrt((4-y^2+y^2)/(4-y^2))=sqrt(4/(4-y^2)=2/sqrt(4-y^2).

Comment: @Mars I understand you now. I did not notice you wrote $ds = \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}$. Yes that would work too for a cylinder. If you parametrize the surface as $(\sqrt{4-y^2}, y, z)$, you will get what you wrote and that should give you the same answer.

Comment: @Math_Lover I'm curious what parameterization you used to get $ds=\sqrt{4-y^2}dydz$?

Comment: @Mars I was just checking my notes where I did the working yesterday. I think I may have made a mistake. What I did was to simply take the arc length for any given $z$ which is $\sqrt{1+ (x')^2} \ dy$ but that should not be different than what you get from parametrization. Let me come back in a few minutes after checking further.

Comment: @Mars Yes I do have a mistake. I see that now. I also know why the answer still matched. It is just a coincidence. Let me edit and apologies.

Comment: I am getting _extended discussion in comments_ warning but if you want, we can move this to chat. There are a few things I can clarify which should help about why the answer matched and also how I would have gone about it without getting to unit normal vector.